# Destroy customer sessions programatically

Tags: event-observer, customer, session

Even if I'm logged out of the site, I see my information in Online customers section in Magento admin if I'm not closing the window which seems to be normal Magento flow.

*How can I destroy my session completely so that when I'm logged out, website will track me as a guest user?*

I've tried firing `customer_logout` event and cleaning frontend cache using `Mage::app()->cleanCache();` but it doesn't seem to be built for this purpose.

Here is observer function

```
public function flushCache(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        Mage::app()->cleanCache();
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsetAll();
    }
```

Comment: If you want to remove only customer data from the magento session you can try like

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsetAll() ;

Comment: @Abdul: tried it but it didn't help. Please check updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the ***logout()*** function of ***Mage_Customer_Model_Session*** called then

Magento is   ***assign the customer as  guest using***  `$this->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);`

For this reason at magento,you can see ***the customer as guest ***.
also  as per as  system, after fire of **`customer_logout`**  event magento is set  `customer as guest`.So if **you tried to make  change then that may be not reflect**

```
protected function _logout()
{
    $this->setId(null);
    $this->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
    $this->getCookie()->delete($this->getSessionName());
    return $this;
}
```

If you want to remove those assign  then just rewrite **`Mage_Customer_Model_Session`**

and remove the code:

> $this->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);

### rewrite class:

> ```
> <?php
> class  [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Session extends Mage_Customer_Model_Session{
>
>  protected function _logout()
>     {
>         $this->setId(null);
>         $this->getCookie()->delete($this->getSessionName());
>         return $this;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

This may be help you.